# can't find installSubscribtionHandlers method in apollo-server-express source code?

Tags: express, http, graphql, apollo-server

How come `installSubscriptionHandlers` method is not part of **apollo-server-express** [source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/main/packages/apollo-server-express) and this method is mentioned here in apollo-server [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/data/subscriptions/#using-with-middleware-integrations)

```
  const http = require('http');
  const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

  const express = require('express');

  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
  server.applyMiddleware({app})

  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);
```

This code works and doesn't show any error despite `installSubscriptionHandlers` being not a method exported from any module in the package source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/data/subscriptions/#using-with-middleware-integrations) linked to are for apollo-server v2, which is maintained on the `version-2` branch of the repo. The default `main` branch is (at present) used to maintain v3.

In v2, the method `installSubscriptionHandlers` exists on the class `ApolloServerBase` exported from the package [apollo-server-core](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/version-2/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L951).